# * mark in Nodes in svn revion graph in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

Could anyone please explain the meaning of * symbol in on the node and its usage. I am seeing this after doing merge operations.

Stackoverflow not allowing to post a picture for me if anyone needed please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it shows which revision is included in a tag or branch you've created. For example I have a file with revisions 3*, 10, 13, 32*, 34* and I have created 3 tags from my trunk. These tags were created with revision 8, 33 and 35.

So revision 3 is included in my tag I've created with revision 8, revision 32 is included in my tag with revision 33 etc.

Revisions 10 and 13 are not marked with * because the higher revision 32 was tagged.

Due to this fact, I think that it is related to the creation of tags and/or branches.

I hope you understand my explanations ...

Comment: Correct.  The graph does not show tags as it would be too noisy.  So it puts an * next to items that are tagged, and the tooltip lists the tags.